# Report Builder Hyperlink Action - Not Displaying Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

I have a database field (that populates a number) that needs to be appended onto a base URL.

In ReportBuilder 3.0 > Textbox Properties > Hyperlink Action > To URL.  I have tried the following 3 things to made a Textbox a dynamic hyperlink:

1.) I get a parameter error (this code would work on RB 1.0) - cannot generate Run screen

```
=parameters!HttpPrefix.value + "://" + Parameters!ServerName.Value +    "example.com/id=" + Fields!SurveyURL.toString()
```

2.) Can Run, I get the first part of the URL but the string can not be created in my browser the URL appears as:
http://example.com/id=Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.OnDemandReportObjectModel.FieldImpl

```
="http://example.com/id=" + Fields!SurveyURL.toString()
```

3.) Does not allow me to run.

```
="javascript:void(window.top.location.href='https://example.com?id=" +   CStr(Fields!SurveyURL.Value) + "')"
```

I have an additional textbox (to prove the field works) called Fields!SurveyURL correctly generating data, usually "12345678" in this example I expect: example.com/id=12345678

Comment: if your SurveyURL is Integer then try this Expression `="http://www.example.com/id=" + Cstr(Sum(Fields!SurveyURL.Value))`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Chanom.

Turns out looking at the .RDL in Notepad that the XML around the hyperlink was all messed up which prevented me from saving.

I ended up using what you wrote (without the sum):

```
="http://example.com/id=" + Cstr(Fields!SurveyURL.Value)
```